# Manga about a girl who finds her half sister after years of her father being a douche

Tags: story-identification, manga

I’m looking for an online manga where the female lead is a noble lady, and her father is a gambler, I believe. She finds out that she has a half sister that is a mercenary and the sister is brought into the house. The female lead is determined to give her sister a good life. I believe the sister had black hair, but i’m
not sure.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "beating a douche"? Do you mean "being a douche"?

Comment: Do you know which manga sites you tend to frequent? Was it in color? Black and white? Do you know the hair color of the protagonists? Do you know what sort of noble she was: queen, princess, empress, baroness?

Comment: And can you elaborate on the fantasy or science fiction aspects of the manga?

Comment: It was a colored manga, and I believe I read it on Lady Manga. The female lead was a noble of middle rank, I don’t remember which position though. I do believe her personality was more closed off and serious. It was also more on the fantasy side as in kings, queens, empires, and such.

Comment: That sounds medieval, but not necessarily fantasy. Is there magic? Reincarnation? Miracles? Isekai?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is *[Countess and the Blade](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/countess-and-the-blade)*.

> Charlotte De Perol is a beautiful lady with a heartbreaking past. She has endured long **years of abuse and threats from her mother while her father was busy chasing girls and wasting the family's fortune**. But on the day of her grandfather's funeral, Charlotte becomes the countess instead of her father. Out of resentment, cruel father locates his **long forgotten daughter named Kara** to steal the title back from her daughter Charlotte.

[image: Cover page, showing the sisters]

The setting is vaguely European; there is little magic involved but it is present, so this is on-topic.

As mentioned in the synopsis, the main character abruptly discovers that she has a half sister, a mercenary, after her scumbag father tries to recruit her to take over the family title after he is passed over. This doesn't work out, and the two quickly become close.

Comment: Ah, thank you! This is one of the first mangas I read, so I didn’t remember much.

Comment: @kairosene You're welcome. If this is the correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour).